# Grails Criteria HQL Many-to-Many with group by

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, criteria

I have two domains related through a many-to-many relationship, **Project** and **ProjectCategory**, where projects can have many categories, and one category might be assigned to several projects. So:

```
class ProjectCategory {
   String name
   ...
}

class Project {
   static hasMany = [categories : ProjectCategory]
   ...
}
```

I want to count how many projects exists for each category. The **SQL** to accomplish that is quite simple:

```
select cat.name category, count(pcat.project_categories_id ) projCount
  from project_project_category pcat, 
       project_category cat
 where pcat.project_category_id = cat.id
 group by project_category_id
```

Which returns something like this:

```
category    |  projCount
'cat_1'     |  3
'cat_2'     |  4
'cat_3'     |  1
...
```

Now, the question is, how to do this using Criteria or HQL, something which looks more "Grails/Groovy style"?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

*I've managed to resolve in **HQL**:*

```
def result  = ProjectCategory.executeQuery(
    ''' select c.name, count(p.id)
          from Project p join p.categories c
         group by c ''' )
```

Comment: Look at projections: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Comment: I've found this article about named queries with projections, for further reference: http://wiredforcode.com/blog/2011/03/20/named-queries-with-projections-in-grails/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the criteria API and projections gets you something like this:

```
def results = Project.createCriteria().list() {
    createAlias('categories', 'catalias')
    projections {
        groupProperty('catalias.name')
        count('id')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked fine! Please tell me, why do I need to use the createAlias? There is no reference in the "criteria" part of the manual to this [Grails Criteria Reference](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) .

Comment: The grails criteria API is a thin (limited) wrapper on top of the Hibernate criteria API. You can see what actions are available by looking at the [HibernateCriteriaBuilder](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html) javadoc, and read the Hibernate documentation section on criteria to get into more specifics of what the methods do. In this case, you cannot use an association as a `groupProperty`, but you can use a named alias for an association. (ie. `groupProperty('categories.name')` wouldn't work)

Comment: Thank you, I will "delve" in this documentation, since I can't avoid anymore :)